# Android - Bold Tags Do Not Seem to Affect URL Text In Strings.xml

Tags: java, android, string, android-layout, textview

I have a string containing a URL which I would like to make bold. For some reason when I add the bold tags - the text still does not appear in this manner.

I'm sure it is something very simple. Does anyone know how this can be resolved?

Example:

```
<string name="updated_text">This is sample text. If this doesn’t work, go to<b> <a href="news.google.com">http://news.google.com</a></b> to find more infomation.</string>
```

Comment: No... If you look at the method I'm using - and look at the example you just showed - they look almost exactly the same: it isn't working (with the bold tag)

Comment: The accepted answer there uses `Html.fromHtml()`, which you do not appear to be using. String XML does not support the `<a>` tag, as per the [String Resources](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html#FormattingAndStyling) documentation.

Comment: What about the bold tags?

Comment: While the bold _should_ work, the parser may be giving up on formatting once it finds the `<a>` tag. Start by removing the `<a>` tag and see if that fixes the bold. Though since you probably want to keep that, you may also just want to move to a slightly different implementation now.

Comment: I used <string name="updated_text">This is sample text. If this doesn’t work, go to<b> http://news.google.com</b> to find more infomation.</string> and it still isn't appearing bold

Comment: Check out the [String Resources](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html#FormattingAndStyling) documentation again. The very first item under the formatting and styling section says that you need to escape apostrophes.

Comment: I used <string name="updated_text">This is sample text. If this doesn\’t work, go to<b> news.google.com</b>; to find more infomation.</string> and it still isn't appearing bold

Comment: I'm using the method provided in the android documentation

Answer (score 0):

try it like this , this should work

```
myTextView.setText(Html.fromHtml(getResources().getString(R.string.updated_text)));
```

Comment: Ok. How about the bold tags in my question?

Comment: I used <string name="updated_text">This is sample text. If this doesn\’t work, go to<b> news.google.com</b>; to find more infomation.</string> and it still isn't appearing bold